# Custom Domains for shared Plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using the D1 Shared Plan, which offers 1Gb of storage and Custom domains.

I tried to associate a custom domain, but when I click on the "Custom domains" menu item, I get the following message error:
"SSL bindings to custom domains can be used in Basic plans and higher."
(view the [error message picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X4bj.png))

According to this message, I think the [pricing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwVvQ.png) is not right.

How can I get custom domains with shared plan?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was having the same problem the solution is going to https://manage.windowsazure.com (AKA the Old Portal) and configure the domain name there.

Comment: That's not the problem the OP is having. It has nothing to do with which portal is in use. The OP is running into SSL binding issues, as SSL isn't available on the shared plan.

Comment: I can confirm I am able to configure the custom domain from https://manage.windowsazure.com/ , instead on the new portal https://portal.azure.com/ is not allowed for me. I can't say what is the reason.

Answer (score 3):

The service plans are correct, Azure Web Apps allows for custom domains at the 'shared tier' or higher (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/)
Since the error you are seeing is associated with SSL, make sure there is no SSL bindings and you are not using HTTPS. SSL is not supported for the shared web app service plan.
If SSL is required, you will need to scale-up to the 'basic tier', which supports custom domains AND also SSL.
Scaling-up existing Web App: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/